# Does Superman have a son?

Tags: dc, superman

In the movie *Superman Returns*, Lois Lane's son is shown to be the result of Superman getting his super on in Lois Lane at some point in the past. Is there any comics reference to this? Do Superman and Lois ever have a kid (which he doesn't know about) in the comics?

Comment: Larry Niven suggests that [Superman may have children, but not by Lois Lane](http://www.rawbw.com/~svw/superman.html) (Fair warning, that link is mildly NSFW and more than slightly PG-13)

Comment: You might as well try to swallow the ocean. In short, it's happened many many times, but (mostly) in elseworlds or what-if stories; http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_as_a_father

Comment: Haha .. @JasonBaker .. "would emerge with the muzzle velocity of a machine gun bullet", umm yeah.. that would put Lois in some amount of Pain.

Comment: @Gomes So just like Hancock then.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward question that could have been easily answered through Google.

Comment: "getting his super on in **Lois' Lane**" Misplaced apostrophe... or ingenious pun?

Comment: @PartyKingThrandeezy it is, and it was, and that's ok, we have tons of those questions and they're perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: To answer your question properly you've got to first ask by author, because with comics each author "reboots" the series. In superman returns he has a son with lois lane. So yes he has a son but at the same time superman has never had a son because there are so many "different" superman authors so to answer you question. I will say the answer boils down to "Depends witch superman". this is why the comic book world can be hard to follow you can like X superhero but not when Y does it.

Comment: No less that 44 different heirs throughout the mythos listed here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_dynasty

Comment: I would think to continue the Superman storyline, he would have to have kids to carry on his name and his powers. Just throwing that idea out there

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this has happened quite a few times, including adoptions. As far as I know, the only one that has occurred since the *New 52* reboot is **Jon Lane Kent**.

### Superboy

[image: Superboy - Jon Lan Kent]

The latest incarnation of Superboy in the New 52 is Jon Lane Kent, who is Superman's son from an alternate future. In this series, he's actually more powerful than his father, because he was born under a yellow sun but has his father's Krpytonian genetics. The majority of the story takes place in the future, and Superman features only in flashbacks of an occasional crossover.

> I believe he dies in the latest issue of Superboy.

Also, the previous Superboy in the New 52 was a clone of Jon Kent named Kon-El, who was genetically engineered from Kal-El and Lois Lane, arguably making him also their son.

### Otherwise

There are literally dozens of other cases where Superman is depicted as having children. Typically, these are single-panel images, showing "Superman's happy ending", and often the children are adopted. In many of these stories, Superman has a child with Wonder Woman, not Lois Lane, presumably on the theory that another superhero would be more likely to.. survive? ... the process.

One significant departure from this is the *Elseworlds* story *Son of Superman*:

[image]

This story also feature Jon Kent, son of Kal-El and Lois Lane. However, the Elseworlds stories are well outside the mainstream continuity, taking place entirely in their own separate universes. (In this story, for example, Pete Ross and Lana Lang are terrorists, funded by Wonder Woman, and Lex Luthor runs the Justice League.)

Comment: Are any of these canonical? Can you offer any genuinely in-canon examples?

Comment: So it's an alternate reality. Are there any from the prime reality?

Comment: He comes from an alt universe though.

Comment: @Richard I haven't read all of the issues listed in the link you posted but as far as I can tell, all of them are either alternate universes or non-canon one-offs (many of them from *Showcase*). I'm not clear on whether Superboy is supposed to be part of the main continuity or not.

Comment: I have a hazy recollection of seeing a comic in which Superman had two sons, Jor-el II who had super powers like his father, and Kal-el II who was non-super like his mother. But it was a very long time ago (1960s) and I can't recall much else about it.

Answer (score 10):

Since Mike wrote his answer, another iteration has debuted in the current DC main continuity: [Jonathan Samuel Kent](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Samuel_Kent)

[image]

Jon is the son of the pre-[Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_(comics)) versions of Superman and Lois Lane. These versions of characters were reintroduced during the 2015 [Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(comics)) crossover event. At the conclusion of Convergence, Lois gave birth to Jon, and they all resettled into the current continuity.

Their arrival in current continuity was a retcon: they arrived several years before 2015's storytelling. This allowed the family to establish a life in the background of the New 52 world, and for Jon to grow into childhood.

In 2016, a series of events propels the family into the foreground. Jon's mother's  anonymous reporting on the machinations of Intergang draw unwanted attention from that quarter.  The native New 52 Superman apparently dies, and has not, as yet, been revived. This pushes Jon's father to take on the Superman mantle publicly. Jon's powers begin to manifest for the first time. New 52 Lois Lane apparently dies, pushing Jon's mother into that role.

As of this writing, Jon's activities as Superboy are still in their early stages, but he is now an established part of the current continuity.

Update: Via the intervention of a reintroduced [Mister Mxyzptlk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mxyzptlk), the pre- and post-Flashpoint versions of Superman and Lois Lane have been merged into new versions of the characters having experienced most of both earlier versions' adventures. Thus, Jon's parents are the Superman and Lois Lane native to the main continuity.

So, Jon is the first time that the character actively featured in *Superman* and *Action Comics* has had a biological child in the present time, in continuity. However, Superman *does* know about his son, and (to the best of our knowledge) has since before his birth.