# Can a kryptonian male and a human female conceive a child while on earth?

Tags: dc, krypton

Given that it is biologically possible, can it really happen? Won't the act of ejaculation kill the female from immense speed and force?

Comment: [Obligatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel,_Woman_of_Kleenex), though I'm going to assume you've read it already

Comment: The complete story is actually available online, and I'll be linking it in my answer below.

Comment: You seem to be asking two distinct questions, both of which are answerable; Can a human and a Kryptonian have sex (yes) and Can a human and a Kryptonian conceive a child (yes). The two acts are, however, not the same thing.

Comment: In which continuity? Only comics? Which comics?

Comment: http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_as_a_father

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9751/29220

Comment: @Himarm seems like a correct duplicate target.

Comment: __Related__: http://orig03.deviantart.net/be34/f/2014/319/4/8/first_time_is_always_awkward_xd_by_nebezial-d86klrp.jpg

Comment: There seem to be some odd assumptions here. Kryptonians are indeed “People of Steel,” with commensurate strength, speed, and durability, but that by no means implies that every biological process you can think of has to be subject to some scaling law. On the rare occasions when a Kryptonian is injured, does their blood spurt out like a firehose? In all the things I’ve seen, it just seems to leak out normally, so Kryptonian hearts don’t pump correspondingly fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can a Kryptonian have a sex with a human? **Yes.**

Can a Kryptonian and a human have a child? Yes, it's happened [a couple of times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81883/does-superman-have-a-son)

Wouldn't that child kick the mother to death from the inside? Kryptonians are solar-powered. A newborn would be powerless

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the mechanics of it have been discussed in the comics, but [it has happened several times](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_as_a_father).

A few recent examples:

- [Johnathan Samuel Kent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Samuel_Kent) - Son of Superman and Lois in *Convergence: Superman #2*
- [Jon Lane Kent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superboy_(Jon_Lane_Kent)) - Son of Superman and Lois Lane in an alternate timeline in Superboy (vol. 5) #19

The earliest reference I've found is one in the 1949 Superman daily comic in the newspapers. Given the pregnancy was mentioned offhand in a 1946 strip suggests that it was not an entirely unexpected product of their joining.

Comment: I can't post an answer because Imgur is acting up, but they also conceived a child in the _Injustice_ universe.

Comment: Yeah. I was going to put up scans of the Dailies showing the pregnancy announcement and Clark holding the baby. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

Larry Niven has covered this question extensively in a somewhat famous essay, [Man of Steel, Woman of Kleenex](http://www.rawbw.com/~svw/superman.html) (originally published in 1971). Niven takes as given all of the various powers Superman is reputed to have at the time of his writing (they have, after all, changed a bit over the years).

The conclusion Niven reaches is that, with some extensive contrivance involving gold kryptonite (which I don't think is a think in current continuity but was at the time) and artificial insemination, and ignoring genetic incompatibilities as so much science fiction has over the decades, it might be possible to fertilize an egg and produce a viable embryo, but the first time the foetus kicked, the mother would be in some real trouble.

I have never seen this essay refuted, or even really questioned, and really, it still more or less holds together, and the summary answer is: yes, with a lot of effort, but it's probably not a very good idea.